# Robocopy specific files from Compare-Object

Tags: windows, powershell, csv, robocopy

I'm trying to use robocopy to copy specific files to a new location. Below I am comparing a directory to a csv file to look for new files. I get the new files into the $files variable with the full name

```
$files = Compare-Object $csv $location -Property fullname | 
Select-Object FullName | Where-Object {!($_.psiscontainer)} | foreach{$_.FullName}
```

Below is the code im using for robocopy. Is this the correct sytnax?

```
robocopy $src $dest $files
```

When i run this I get a invalid parameter. How can I copy the new files ($files) from the old location to the new with robocopy?

Thank You!

Comment: If you are using Robocopy then you don't even need to compare the folders, Robocopy does that for you. I think you need to pull up a command prompt and do a `robocopy /?` to look at it's options. I'm guessing `Robocopy [source] [destination] /s /copyall /log+:Log.txt` would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly agree with @TheMadTechnician on this one. If I had to do what you are trying to do this is kind of what I would come up with based on some of your code above. One line of Robocopy turned into a bit of a mess.

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\Temp" -Recurse | Export-CSV "C:\filelisting.csv" -NoTypeInformation 

$csv1 = Import-CSV "C:\Filelisting.csv"
$folder2 = "C:\TestFolder"
$dest = "C:\Temp\Test"

Compare-Object $($csv1 | ? { $_.PSIsContainer -ne $true }) $folder2 -Property FullName | 
Foreach-Object { ROBOCOPY ([System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($_.FullName)) $dest ([System.IO.Path]::GetFileName($_.FullName)) "/copyall /log+:C:\Log.txt" }
```